# how to create a new variable in a loop

Tags: python, jes

I'm trying to make a function that prints n number of rows of the following sequence

```
1  
2 3  
4 5 6  
7 8 9 10  
11 12 13 14 15  
...
```

this is what I have so far:

```
def numTriangle(n):  
    #n = number of rows  
    integers = range(0,n-1)  
    val = 1  
    places = 1  
    for num in integers:  
        print val   
        val = val + 1
```

I've realized that I need to make a loop in which it prints the value, then adds one, but also creates a new variable that is one greater than the previous and prints the original value + 1 and the new variable and so on. How would I create a new variable for each line, or are there any other alternatives to this function, such as printing an additional part of the index for each row?

Comment: Break the problem down into basic components and start programming.  You know you need a loop, `range(1, N)` will work good for that.  You know you need to print numbers on a continuous line until a certain count is met then print a new line.  Keep track of your current count, expected count per row and increment count per row, reset count when it makes sense.  Get something started and edit your question to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to do your homework for you, but you at least have a basic description of your plan. Here is a pretty minimal version.

```
def pyramid(n):
    k = 1
    for i in range(n):
        print ' '.join(map(str, range(k, k+i+1)))
        k += i + 1
```

Here is a version that is more verbose.

```
def pyramid(n):
    k = 1
    for i in range(1, n +1):
        first_number = k
        next_row_first_number = k + i
        numbers = range(first_number, next_row_first_number)
        numbers_as_strings = map(str, numbers)
        line = ' '.join(numbers_as_strings)
        print line
        k = next_row_first_number
```

And multiple loops!

```
def pyramid(n):
    k = 1
    for i in range(1, n +1):
        first_number = k
        next_row_first_number = k + i
        numbers = range(first_number, next_row_first_number)
        line = ""
        for num in numbers:
            line = line + str(num) + ' '
        print line
        k = next_row_first_number
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces your output:

```
n = 6; y= 1;

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range (0,i):
        print y,
        y = y+1;
    print "\n"
```

Note the indentation, indentation defines the scopes.